# Can't disable xDebug for Composer

Tags: php, composer-php, xdebug, php-7

I'm having trouble disabling xDebug.  I've commented out the zend_extension from the configuration file as suggested [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#xdebug-impact-on-composer)

*/etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini*

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
;zend_extension=/usr/lib/xdebug/modules/xdebug.so
xdebug.max_nesting_level=200
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=192.168.10.1
xdebug.idekey=phpstorm
```

After restarting Apache2, I still get the following error message when I run composer.

> You are running composer with xdebug enabled. This has a major impact
>   on runtime performance. See https://getcomposer.org/xdebug

I found another xdebug.ini file and it's also seems to be disabled there:

```
cat /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/xdebug.ini
zend_extension=xdebug.so
;zend_extension=/usr/lib/xdebug/modules/xdebug.so
xdebug.max_nesting_level=200
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=192.168.10.1
xdebug.idekey=phpstorm
```

Do I need to restart PHP, how do I do that?

```
$ sudo service php restart
php: unrecognized service
```

Comment: You need to restart Apache.

    `$ sudo service apache2 restart`

PHP runs as Apache module.

Comment: No, you don't. PHP on the command line does not need a restart (unless you're running fpm).

Comment: `zend_extension=xdebug.so` is still enabled, so that will probably still load.

Comment: @Farkie, that was it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can find same answer here...
[disabling-xdebug-when-running-composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31083195/disabling-xdebug-when-running-composer/39985285#39985285)

Comment: Just linking to a different question is not much of an answer. I'd recommend going over the [tips for writing a good answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). If you just want to refer to some information might as well do it in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

**IF** you are - like me - working in a dev-VM, where you are always root, you can add the following code to your .bashrc to temporarily disable XDebug when running composer:

```bash
# Composer WITHOUT XDebug
composer(){
    xdbEnabled=$(php -r 'echo extension_loaded('xdebug');')

    hasBeenDisabled='0' # not needed, just for clarification and better readability

    if [ $xdbEnabled == '1' ]
        then
            echo 'XDebug is enabled. Disabling temporarily.'
            phpdismod xdebug
            hasBeenDisabled='1'
    fi

    php /path/to/composer.phar "$@" # or just 'composer "$@"', if it is installed globally

    if [ $hasBeenDisabled == '1' ]
        then
            phpenmod xdebug
            echo 'XDebug has been reenabled.'
    fi
}
```

If you are not root, you would have to call it with `sudo composer [args]`, since `phpdismod` and `phpenmod` require root.

**However, you should *not* do that** on your host system or any other environment that is not easily recoverable and sandboxed, since running composer as root is potentially dangerous (Packages can register scripts that run on install and/or update, and you can't trust every package you require).

**EDIT:**
This works for PHP >= 7. For PHP 5, replace `phpdismod` and `phpenmod` with `php5dismod` and `php5enmod` (not tested).

**2nd Edit:** AFAIK, `phpenmod` and `phpdismod` are only available on Ubuntu/Debian based systems.