# cache:clear symfony allowed memory size

Tags: php, symfony

for a few days I have been having difficulty performing the cache:clear command on my symfony 5.4 application. I have already increased the memory_limit of php, which I don't understand is why it happens suddenly when everything was going well before.

I think a bundle is the problem but I have no way of knowing which one.
Here is the error I get :

```
 // Clearing the cache for the dev environment with debug true                                                          


Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 2097288 bytes) in /var/www/oasis/vendor/symfony/cache/Adapter/PhpArrayAdapter.php on line 362

In PhpArrayAdapter.php line 362:
                                                                                             
  Error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 2097288 bytes)
```

do you know a way to fix this problem please ?

Comment: For me it was xDebug that was turned on in console.

Comment: hello @Justinas how did you disable xdebug in the console?

Comment: Via console's [config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31083195/disabling-xdebug-when-running-composer) adding `xdebug.mode=none`