# How to temporary disable Xdebug for cache/container building code, but that it remains enabled for the rest of the execution?

Tags: php, symfony, xdebug, xdebug-3

I have the following Xdebug config:

```ini
xdebug.mode=develop
xdebug.start_with_request=true
xdebug.client_host=docker.for.mac.localhost
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.discover_client_host=false
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.trigger_value=""
xdebug.cli_color=1
xdebug.var_display_max_depth=-1
xdebug.var_display_max_children=-1
xdebug.var_display_max_data=-1
```

When doing `composer update` there will be a call to `cache:clear` command that will hang. It will work only if `-dxdebug.mode=off` (or `xdebug.mode=off` in .ini file).

I can do work-around in composer.json:

from

```json
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
        }
    },
```

to

```json
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "-dxdebug.mode=off bin/console cache:clear": "php-script",
        }
    },
```

---

But now if I run some random command (e.g. `bin/console make:entity` that needs container re-build then Xdebug will be still turned on and command will hang on same cache build process.

Comment: Can this help ? this https://github.com/ddev/ddev/issues/3563 or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31083195/disabling-xdebug-when-running-composer

Comment: @b126 No, I would like to disable xDebug only one portion of current code. Rest should be runned with xDebug enabled

Comment: The real question should be: Why does Xdebug make your command hang.

Comment: @Derick Because there is tons of classes invoked when building container

Comment: @Justinas: The issue is still open https://github.com/symfony/flex/issues/936. Did you try `xdebug.profiler_enable = off`? Seems to work sometimes